# Difference between entering URL and clicking bookmark in the context of logging into Wi-Fi network

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, bookmarks, url

I have noticed that when I access some partially restricted WiFi network (and my Windows 7 displays information about additional login information that may be needed) then whenever I open Chrome, it:

- fails to load pages set as start pages,
- fails to open any clicked bookmark,

with ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error each time.

I must always enter some URL manually and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then and only them I'm redirected to Wi-Fi login page.

Why? What is the difference between manually entering URL and clicking some bookmark or using pages set as home pages or what is the difference between method of opening pages -- from this point of view?

For me, absolutely any method of changing current URL to any other should result in displaying Wi-Fi login page, if such login is required in particular Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Are your bookmarks HTTPS but you manually type HTTP?

Comment: @Spiff Seems so, but I'll double check tomorrow and report here.